# Multiple filters in DAX with OR Keyword

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

I have a requirement where I need to evaluate column from multiple tables and select required records from my Fact table in my SSAS tabular Model.

Eg:
Pick Records from FactA where:

```
 ('DimA'[DimA Group] = "Contract" AND'DimB'[DimB Group] = "Contract") OR ('DimA'[DimA Group] = "Commercial", 'DimB'[DimB Group] = "Commercial")
```

Below is the DAX is have:

```
MeasureA :=
CALCULATE(SUM('FactA'[Amount Single]),filter(('DimA'[DimA Group] = "Contract", 'DimB'[DimB Group] = "Contract"),
('DimA'[DimA Group] = "Commercial", 'DimB'[DimB Group] = "Commercial"),))
```

This error I get is Operator Or Expression '()' is not supported in the current context.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MeasureA :=
CALCULATE(
  SUM('FactA'[Amount Single]),
  FILTER(
    CROSSJOIN(VALUES('DimA'[DimA Group]), VALUES('DimB[DimB Group])),
   ('DimA'[DimA Group] = "Contract" && 'DimB'[DimB Group] = "Contract")
   || ('DimA'[DimA Group] = "Commercial" && 'DimB'[DimB Group] = "Commercial")
  )
)
```

More on this pattern is described [here](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/).